# Getting the exact HTML format of a table scraped from a webpage in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping

I am trying to get a table scraped and have gotten as far as getting all of the HTML for the table but have then gotten stuck.

```
Sub clickFormButton()
Dim oHtml       As HTMLDocument
Dim oElement    As IHTMLElement

Set oHtml = New HTMLDocument


With CreateObject("WINHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1")
.Open "GET", "http://www.marketwatch.com/tools/quotes/lookup.asp?siteID=mktw&Lookup=agnico-eagle+mines&Country=us&Type=All", False
.send
oHtml.body.innerHTML = .responseText

End With


Dim wsTarget As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
i = 1
Set wsTarget = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

For Each oElement In oHtml.getElementsByClassName("results")
wsTarget.Range("A" & i) = oElement.Children(0).innerText
i = i + 1
Next

End Sub`
```

This returns the data that I want, however it returns it all in one cell. Where as I want the scraped data to format in a similar table that it is in HTML by following the TR and TD tags.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the `split` function for this task.

The code snippet

```
split(oElement.Children(0).innerText, "<\TR>")
```

will return an array of strings where each element is a row in your HTML table.  From there you can run a similar command with `"<\TD>"` replacing `"<\TR>"` to split each row into individual cells.  From there you will probably want to clean up the extraneous `<TD>`s and `<TR>`s in the resulting cells.

Comment: @Ross McConeg Yeah.  Fixed